# Como executar um programa .py pelo IDLE do python no Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo a programar em python e fiz um pequeno programa, mas não consigo executá-lo pelo terminal(IDLE ou sheel)do python
nome do programa:salario_real.py
erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Me parece que vc está no modo de comandos do interpretador Python, o Python Shell. Para executar um programa em Python, vc precisar digitar `python meuPrograma.py` no prompt de comando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar um script Python, você precisa estar no prompt de comandos do Windows, então basta digitar o seguinte:

```
python meuPrograma.py
```

Ou se quiser executar o script no IDLE de forma interativa, terá que usar uma função para isso.

Executando script no IDLE com a função [execfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile):

```
execfile('meuPrograma.py')
```

Desta forma conseguira executar script no IDLE.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21650698/5429980).

Answer (score 1):

Com a tela do `IDLE` aberta você deve executar os seguintes passos:

1. Clique sobre o menu `File`;
2. Clique sobre a opção `Open`;
3. Navegue até a pasta onde se encontra o seu arquivo de script (meu_arquivo.py);
4. Selecione o arquivo;
5. Clique sobre o botão `Abrir`.

Neste momento será aberto o arquivo que você selecionou.

Agora, para você fazer o arquivo que foi aberto ser executado no IDLE, você deve pressionar a tecla `F5`.

Neste momento o seu script `.py` será executado na tela do `IDLE`.